# Access audio from Linux server on iPad Mini

Tags: linux, audio, itunes, mp3, ipad

This is driving me crazy, I'm trying to enable playback of mp3s/flac audio stored on a home linux server on a iPad mini.

Please can someone explain what software is required on the linux side of things and how to configure it on the ipad.

Can iTunes even play this back?

Edit: The goal is to discover what software or services I need to install on a Ubuntu Linux system to allow an iPad Mini to playback music contained on the Ubuntu system.

Comment: Give us some more info on your setup. What have you tried? There are various ways of doing this, how are you trying to o it?

Comment: Ubuntu linux runs on a computer acting as a server. It has video and audio NFS shares which I use on XBMC running on a Raspberry Pi. I want to know how to share the audio to an iPad mini. I don't know what services/software I need to install to get this streaming audio or showing up in iTunes/Music. The point of this question is that I don't know how to try and do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of three ways of doing this. You can set up a smb share with the music and access that using `BuzzPlayer` from the iPad, you can use a dedicated streaming server like mediatomb on Linux or you can set up an http server and play the files with a web browser or something like `oplayer`. Personally, I use the smb solution, it is very easy to set up.

1. Set up the smb share. Ubuntu have a nice HowTo [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide). It essentially boils down to right clicking on the folder in question and selecting "share".
2. There may be other apps with this capability, but I know that [`BuzzPlayer`](http://bugunsoft.com/buzzplayer/) works. It is a paid app but definitely worth it. It can play both movie and music files streamed over an smb connection. Just install it, go to the network shares pane and you will be able to see your Linux share.

That's all folks.

Comment: Thanks. Does mediatomb mean that it'll show up on the iPad without the need for an additional app?

Comment: I don't think the is any way to make the native music app see network shares if that's what you mean, no.